# ¿Qué significan los : en haskell?

Tags: operador, haskell

estoy aprendiendo haskell y encuentro con regularidad los símbolos ":" en los programas y no se qué significan. Por ejemplo:

```
module DecBin where
 decBin :: Int -> [Int]
 decBin x = if x < 2 then [x]
            else (x `mod` 2) : decBin (x `div` 2)
```

¿Qué son los ":" en la última línea del código?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:` es el constructor de listas en haskell. Lo podés pensar así:

Suponé que `xs` es del tipo `[A]` (lista de A), y `x` un elemento del tipo `A`. `x:xs` se lee como "x pegado a xs" y es una lista que tiene como primer elemento a `x`, y el resto es la lista `xs`.

Esto viene de la definición recursiva de lista en haskell. Una lista tiene una de las siguientes formas: es una lista vacía o es un elemento "pegado" a otra lista.

Por ejemplo, lo que entendemos como `[1, 2, 3]` internamente en haskell es representado como

`1: (2: (3: []))`

Answer (score -4):

Los `:` en Haskell son un operador de construcción de listas. En este caso, la línea de código se está utilizando para agregar un elemento al principio de una lista. Por ejemplo, si llamamos la función decBin con el argumento 5, esto es lo que sucedería:

- x se inicializa con el valor 5.
- La condición `x < 2` es falsa, por lo que se ejecuta la segunda parte de la expresión if (la que está después del else).
- Se calcula el resto de la división de `x (5) entre 2, lo que da 1`. Este valor se agrega al principio de la lista vacía que se está construyendo, dando como resultado [1].
- Se llama recursivamente a la función decBin con el argumento x div 2, que es igual a 5 div 2, que es igual a 2.
- Se repiten los pasos 1 a 3 con el nuevo valor de x (2). En este caso, la condición x < 2 es verdadera, por lo que se devuelve la lista [0].
- La función decBin que se llamó recursivamente en el paso 4 devuelve la lista [0], que se agrega al principio de la lista que se estaba construyendo en el paso 3, dando como resultado la lista final [1, 0].

En resumen, los `:` en Haskell se utilizan para agregar elementos al principio de una lista. Esto se conoce como construcción de listas por concatenación.

Comment: Cuando copies de chatGPT, al menos dale formato para que tenga sentido. Ese es todo el punto de las críticas que te están haciendo (además del plagio)

Comment: cuando x = 2, x < 2 es falso.... o haskell es muy raro....